# Why didn't the gods grant Kratos what he wanted?

Tags: god-of-war

Kratos was merely a mortal who simply wanted to forget some bad memories from his past. That's it.

- He asked gods for it and nobody listened. Instead, he was further dragged into the war.
- After killing Aries, Kratos even tried to commit suicide so that he could end his torment, but gods didn't let him. Instead, he was made new God of War.
- Later, Zeus grew jealous of him and stripped him of his powers and Kratos became mortal again. But, even this time Zeus didn't permanently kill him or remove his bad past memories. Kratos was sent to underworld.
- After killing Sisters of Fate, Kratos and Zeus had fight and in the end, Kratos even decided to give up if Zeus killed him to end his torment (this was a win-win situation for both). But, again Zeus didn't do what Kratos wanted and Athena got killed in the battle.

Why didn't the gods remove bad memories of Kratos instead of pissing him again and again which led to their own deaths?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Athena says straight out that the gods don't have the power to make him forget that he killed his wife and children, and free him from his guilt.

Comment: Because the ancient gods were petty and cruel... Oops wrong franchise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### To put it simply, the Gods do what they want to do.

Actually, Kratos started out asking for the "strength to defeat his enemies", in return for serving Ares. He was granted this strength. But, Because Ares was a God, he did what he wanted, and tried to make Kratos his "ultimate warrior", by forcing him to kill his own family, thus releasing him from anything that might stop him from becoming the ultimate killing machine. This is what sent Kratos off the deep end, having been tricked by the Gods.

Eventually, Ares became jealous of Athena, which is why he chose to wreak havoc on Athens, thereby forcing Athena to ask Kratos for help. Since Kratos had already given the Gods his piece of mind, the only way she could convince him was with an empty promise.

But by killing Ares, this put a *huge* warning sign around Kratos. He was now a *God killer*. He killed Ares, nothing really stopping him form killing anyone else; even Athena, for betraying him yet again. So Athena needed to distract him. By making him the new God of War, all that praise and worship and blood and glory ought to do something to distract him, keeping the rest of the Gods safe.

But, Kratos got bored. Being a God, he did what he wanted to do, and like the rage-fueled toddler that he was, decided to go stomp off and break stuff. Unlike Athena, Zeus was less scared of Kratos, and honestly quite sick of his behaviour by this point. Since you can't kill a God, he needed to strip him of his godhood. Once done (with the Blade of Olympus), he killed Kratos, sending him to the Underworld.

Now Kratos had more to complain about. One: Death wasn't the end he expected. It didn't solve anything in regards to his torment about killing his family. Two: He was the God of War, and Zeus took that away from him; which came hand in hand with the fact that *once again*, he'd been tricked by the Gods.

By this point, Kratos learned that he could end the God's reign by help of the Titans. From Kratos' point of view, this is what he wanted, so; being a God (by his standards), he did what he wanted to do. If he couldn't have anything else, at the very least he could just kill all the other Gods, and be done with it.

But since Zues was still more powerful than Kratos and overpowered him (being the King of all the Gods), when Kratos asked Zeus to kill him, Zeus was at the point that even doing that would be doing what Kratos wanted, and he would deny him even that. This "petulant child" needed to be taught a lesson, like Prometheus getting his guts pecked out daily; so Zeus, being a God, did what he wanted to do.

Kratos, being denied what he wanted, and then Athena being killed in the meantime (which was probably the closest thing Kratos had to a friend or ally in this whole adventure) set his resolve to just end it, and kill all the Gods, which is what he wanted to do from the get go.

This is why Kratos left Greece (well part of; since the Titans were busy remodelling; basically turning everything into a giant wasteland again), and basically renounced his past life, and moved to the nice quiet North, where he settled down, shacked up, and had a son named "Boy".

Answer (score 1):

Ummm. Kratos only told Zeus "I lay down my arms Zeus.... Realease me from this torment..." to trick Zeus in order to gain back the upper hand. Kratos quickly turned around and attacked Zeus, taking the blade of olympus. Athena then came to defend Zeus and got stabbed by Kratos cause she was protecting Zeus. Athena did not stop Zeus from killing Kratos at all.

Comment: Your main point is the first sentence that he was doing it to trick the Zeus. Could you [edit] in some evidence that this really was his motivation?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Please be aware that this is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum: answers are for answering the question, not for nit-picking specific sentences within it. Why did the gods not grant Kratos' wish and erase his memories?